# How can I know the sequence of buttons pressed to show in textviews

Tags: android, button, textview

Hello everyone how are you? I am fine.

I am developing an app where in an activity I have six buttons and six TextViews:
Button 1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6.
TextView1, TextView2, TextView3, TextView4, TextView5, TextView6.

I have to display the text of the buttons in the textviews (getText().toString());
 But I need to display in the TextView1 the first button pressed, no matter if it was the Button1, the Button2, the Button3, the Button4, the Button5 or Button6.
In the second TextView the second button pressed.
In the thirst TextView the third button pressed.

This is my code

package com.flixarts.ar.englishnow;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button opcion1;
    private Button opcion2;
    private Button opcion3;
    private Button opcion4;
    private Button opcion5;
    private Button opcion6;

    private TextView text0;
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text2;
    private TextView text3;
    private TextView text4;
    private TextView text5;
    private TextView text6;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    text0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text0);
    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
    text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
    text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
    text6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text6);

    opcion1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion1);
    opcion2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion2);
    opcion3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion3);
    opcion4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion4);
    opcion5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion5);
    opcion6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion6);


    opcion1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Button opcion1 = (Button)view;
        String textButton = opcion1.getText().toString();
     text0.setText(textButton);

        //writeTextView();
    }

});


opcion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion2 = (Button)view;
        String textButton2 = opcion2.getText().toString();
        text2.setText(textButton2); }});

opcion3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion3 = (Button)view;
        String textButton3 = opcion3.getText().toString();
        text3.setText(textButton3);  } });

opcion4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion4 = (Button)view;
        String textButton4 = opcion4.getText().toString();
        text4.setText(textButton4); } });

opcion5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion5 = (Button)view;
        String textButton5 = opcion5.getText().toString();
        text5.setText(textButton5);  } });

opcion6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion6 = (Button)view;
        String textButton6 = opcion6.getText().toString();
        text6.setText(textButton6);  } });

}
```

}

The problem with this code is that shows the text of the first button in the first textview, the second button in the second textview, the third button on the tirhd textview, etc.

I need to show in the first textview the first button pressed, no matter if it was the butotn1, 2, 3,4, 5, or 6.

So everytime the user press a button from 1 to six it goes setting the text in the textview's in order.

Thanks for reading!
Have a nice day, Mauro.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put buttons and text views into arrays:

```
private Button[] buttons;
private TextView[] tvs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  buttons = new Button[6];
  buttons[0] = findViewById(R.id.opcion1);
  // make the same for all buttons and TVs
}
```

2. Keep index of current click:

```
private int mClickIndex;
```

3. Use same `OnClickListener for all buttons:

```
private View.OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion = (Button)view;
        if (mClickListener >= 6) return;
        tv[mClickIndex].setText(opcion.getText().toString());
        mClickListener++;
    }
  };

...
onCreate() {
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(mOptionsClickListener);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mauro: put all your `TextView` references in a List *[text0,... textn]* and keep an index to the current text view, starting at 0:

```
List<TextView> textViews = Arrays.asList(text1, text1);
int current = 0;
```

Make your activity `quiz` implement `View.OnClickListener` and override `onClick`. Then assign the button caption to the current text view from the array.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textViews.get(current % textViews.size()).setText(((Button)v).getText());
        current++;
    }
```

Incrementing `current` ensures the next button clicked will "hit" the next text view.

Comment: Thank you Eddiel!

Comment: Hi Eddiel, I'm having a Null Pointer error with this code  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Button.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Is indeed weird that the button you are receiving as argument `v` from `onClick` is null when it should be the very button you're clicking. Try moving each step to a separate line until and use the debugger until you find where the problem is.